# Linear Programming: What is the rationale behind the Gauss Jordan Row operations we do after determining the leaving and entering variables?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

Let's say this was the starting iteration table of the simplex method:

[image]

After identifying the entering and leaving variables, we do these Gauss Jordan row operations wherein,

[image]

Why do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

I'm going to address the question *why* the solutions keep the same by these pivot row operations, before addressing the question why we *want* to do these operations.

## Why *can* we do this?

Note that the problem is unchanged after usual row operations: the ones that college students do to systems of linear equations.

$\require{action}$
\begin{array}{cccc} \hline
\texttip{\text{pivot elt}}{selected first} & \texttip{\text{pvt relt } 1}{pivot row element 1} & \cdots & \texttip{\text{pvt relt } n}{pivot row element n} \\ \hline
\texttip{\text{pvt celt } 1}{pivot column element 1} & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
\texttip{\text{pvt celt } 2}{pivot column element 2} & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
\texttip{\text{pvt celt } n}{pivot column element n} & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
\end{array}

In the simplex algorithm, one always choose a *positive pivot element* so that the solution at the RHS is always nonnegative.

1. In step (1b), this is just division by a positive scalar $a_{11}$ of a linear equation.  This won't change the constraint at all.
   \begin{array}{cccc} \hline
   \texttip{1}{pivot element} & \text{new pvt relt } 1 & \cdots & \text{new pvt relt } n \\ \hline
   \text{pvt celt }1 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
   \text{pvt celt }2 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
   \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
   \text{pvt celt }m & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
   \end{array}
2. In step (2), we subtract each other non-pivot row by the current pivot row multiplied by a suitable constant.  The equation
   $$\text{New row} = \text{Current row} (\times 1) - \text{pivot column element} \times \text{new pivot row} \tag{given}\label1$$
   is actually the *pivotal condensation*.

Therefore, such elementary row operations *don't* alter the solutions of the linear equations.

## Why do we *want* this?

In your table, observe that $z = 5x_1 + 4x_2$.  Even thought we *can't* write $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x_1} = 5$ (since each feasible solution is an extreme point/corner of the convex feasible region), but you know that at a certain neighbourhood of the current basic solution, the rate of increase of $z$ with respect to $x_1$ is $5$---that's the maximal rate of increase, that's why we introduce a new decision variable into the basis while kicking out one at a time.